# How to find out what process is using wp_mail?

Tags: wordpress, sendgrid

While enabling Sendgrid plugin I get such a message:

```
SendGrid: wp_mail has been declared by another process or plugin
```

An interesting thing is that I disable all plugins and enabling this plugin I still get this error. Is it possible to see what kind of process is using wp_mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer below scenario, 
1. Maybe plugin not supported your WP version. 
2. This plugin may used WP core class or function because of that this second time declaration error may occur.